# Python: Defining static class variables by using other static variable

Tags: python-3.x, static

How can I define static class members by using other static members?
for instance:

```
class Somefuncs:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print('foo was called')
    functs_dict={'foo':Somefuncs.foo}
```

makes the interpreter raise the Exception: Unresolved reference 'Somefuncs'
even though I'm defining funct_dict within the class Somefuncs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point the class is not really defined.

But you could just write:

```
class Somefuncs:
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print('foo was called')

    functs_dict={'foo': foo}


# Test it
Somefuncs.functs_dict["foo"]()
# Output: foo was called
```

It always refers to the current class